# Converting cURL request to PHP

Tags: php, curl

I've got the following sample cURL request that I'm trying to run through PHP.

```
curl --request PUT \
--url 'https://example.com/' \
--user 'APIKEY:ACCESSTOKEN' \
--header 'content-type: application/json' \
--data '{"TableId": "MyHats","Columns": ["Id","Name"],"Data": [["1","Hat 1"],["2","Hat 2"],["3","Hat 3"]]}' \
```

At first I tried converting an old POST request to use PUT and send the JSON but it didn't seem to work.

```
$ch           = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$api_key:$access_token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
$result       = curl_exec($ch);
$status_code  = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close ($ch);
```

I've also tried the flowing PUT request converted from an example I found online

```
$data_string  = json_encode($data);
$ch           = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$api_key:$access_token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);
$result       = curl_exec($ch);
$status_code  = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close ($ch);
```

The API doesn't have a response but it does return a 302 status code which I'm told is the expected result but they aren't receiving any of the data on their end.